# Trouble finding and printing data with a specific prefix from file

Tags: c++

My program reads from a file database of phone calls and this section of code is supposed to print out some of the phone numbers (and other info) from the file, but only the ones that start with a specified prefix. I can't figure how to make it identify which calls have the correct prefix and only print those ones.

I tried using string.find(prefix) but it's not working.

```
while (1) {
    cout<< "\nE164 prefix for query:"<< endl;
    cin >> prefix;
    if (prefix== "\n" || prefix== "-1") {
        break;
    }

    if (numCalls== 0) {
        cout<< "No Records\n";
    }
    else {
        cout<< "Time      Country  Phone Number    Duration\n";
        for (unsigned int i=0; i< numCalls; ++i) {
            if (call.phonenum.find(prefix)!= string::npos) {
            GetCallInCallDB( calldb, i, call);
            cout<< left<< setw(10) << GetStartCall(call);
            cout<< left<< setw(9)<< GetCountryCodeCall(call);
            cout<< left<< setw(16)<< GetPhoneNumberCall(call);
            cout<< FormatDuration(call)<< endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The if statements work, but the else statement only puts out the header and a random (though correctly formatted) piece of the phone call file.

Comment: *I tried using string.find(prefix) but it's not working.* --> What is not working? Are you getting extra output with numbers that don't have the prefix?  Are you not getting output from numbers that do have the prefix?  Something else?  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Note that `phonenum.find(prefix)` will return 4 when prefix="530" and phonenum = "847-5309".  Is this expected behavior?

Comment: The error possibly exists in `GetStartCall`, `GetCountryCodeCall` or `GetPhoneNumberCall`, so we would need the source of these functions.